# Как оформить "во-первых, вторых, третьих...", если знаков и так переизбыток?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> Сами для себя мы решили, что малая сцена – это творческая лаборатория,
>   во-первых; во-вторых – это ведь «самостоятельный спектакль»; а
>   в-третьих и главных – мы существовали настолько близко к тексту, что
>   сохраняли все указанные автором ремарки, мы были бесконечно бережны с
>   материалом.

(Речь о попытке обойти авторский запрет на инсценировку.)

Точки с запятой - мои.

Стало лучше? хуже?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сами для себя мы решили, что малая сцена – это творческая лаборатория, во-первых; во-вторых – это ведь «самостоятельный спектакль»; **а главное** – мы существовали настолько близко к тексту, что **сохранили** все указанные автором ремарки, мы были бесконечно бережны с материалом.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю такой вариант, по *стандартной* схеме:

*Во-первых, мы решили сами для себя, что малая сцена – это творческая лаборатория; во-вторых – это ведь «самостоятельный спектакль»; а в-главных – мы существовали [или работали] совершенно [или абсолютно] близко к тексту: сохраняли все указанные автором ремарки, были бесконечно бережны с материалом.*

Мне кажется, что ТАК - проще и понятнее.